# angular js post data returning 400 error

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

I have an angular js app that is connected to rest framework. I am trying to post some data to make changes into the rest framework as follows:

```
  $scope.addDegree = function(degree) {
    $http.post('/api/studentacademicprogram/', degree).then(function(response){
        alert('post added');
    }, function(response){
        alert('post not added');
    });
  };
```

Here is how i defined my get from the factory:

```
angular.module('jsonService', ['ngResource'])

    .factory('ProgramsService',function($http) {
        return {
            getItems: function(callback) {
                $http.get('/api/studentacademicprogram/?format=json').success(callback);
            }
        };
    })
```

and here is how i defined my view in the rest framework:

```
class StudentAcademicProgramList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        student_academic_program = Student_academic_program.objects.filter(student=29722)
        serialized_Student_academic_program = StudentAcademicProgramSerializer(student_academic_program, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_Student_academic_program.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = StudentAcademicProgramSerializer(data = request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status= status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class StudentAcademicProgramDetail(APIView):
    def get_objects(self, pk):
    try:
        return Student_academic_program.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Student_academic_program.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
    student_academic_program = self.get_objects(pk)
        serialized_Student_academic_program = StudentAcademicProgramSerializer(student_academic_program)
        return Response(serialized_Student_academic_program.data)
```

But when i try to post some data. it throws back a POST error in the console:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/studentacademicprogram/ 400 (BAD REQUEST)
```

After adding the console as @EliteOctagon suggested, i am getting the following in the console:

```
Object {data: Object, status: 400, headers: function, config: Object}
config: Object
data: Object
headers: Object
Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
Content-Type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
__proto__: Object
method: "POST"
transformRequest: Array[1]
transformResponse: Array[1]
url: "/api/studentacademicprogram/"
__proto__: Object
data: Object
academic_program: Array[1]
student: Array[1]
__proto__: Object
headers: function (name) {
status: 400
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, define the sent variables in json format when using post

```
$scope.addDegree = function(degree) {
   var variablesToSend = {'degree': degree}
   $http.post('/api/studentacademicprogram/', variablesToSend ).then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
      alert('post added');
   }, function(response){
      console.log(response);
      alert('post not added');
   });
};
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. still the same error though :(.

Comment: @crozzfire what do you get when you run the validator in your server? Seeing as you have a .is_valid() function, where does it fail?

Comment: I got a 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) when i removedd the is_valid(). I am guessing it is the format in which the json is being sent. let me add more to the question to clarify